# How does PacketFence work with CentOS firewall?

Tags: centos, firewall, ports

I have a PacketFence installed on CentOS 7 but I need to enable ports 1812 and 1813 for AAA. Despite iptables.conf in PacketFence conf directory having all the necessary rules I still am not able to open the port.

Any idea where to look ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 uses `firewalld` to manage the firewall. `iptables` has been deprecated.

Check [firewalld usage](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html) and/or `man firewalld` for how to enable the ports that you need.

Additionally, search for any intro to firewalld on CentOS 7 for clarification.